# Converting Nasa's Blue Marble into cubic projection

Tags: coordinate-system, software-recommendations

I'm looking for a free tool to convert the cylindrical projection map of the Earth's surface that you can get from Nasa (under the Blue Marble project):
http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view_cat.php?categoryID=1484

to a cubic projection like so:
http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/Normal/ProjPoly/Foldout/Cube/cube.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is another free softwaretool (for windows, mac and linux!) with a convient gui to create the desired projection with just a few simple mouseclicks. The tool is: g.projector, beside  this projection (gmomic cubed square) it supports about 80 other projections!!

download here: http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/gprojector/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found a free tool to convert map images back and forth between different projections. It seems pretty powerful and I was easily able to convert a cylindrical normal projection into a gnomonic cubic (which is what I was looking for).

The tool is available here:
http://www.users.globalnet.co.uk/~arcus/mmps/

A specific example of how to use the tool to do the conversion is here:
http://www.lns.cornell.edu/~seb/celestia/textures.html#2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a special case of a interrupted projection. Although I never used the software personally (a bit expensive for a hobby-cartographer like me, but to be honest there is also a deeply reduced price for personal/noncommerical usage!) I am pretty sure this can be done with Geocart, but perhaps not with one or two mouseclicks. You should contact the developer dan Strebe, who is an authority for projections. http://www.mapthematics.com/
maybe - as this is more a cartographic than a gis question - you should also post this at http://www.cartotalk.com, a good forum for cartographers or ask mr. furuti for further advise.